# flow from setup to teardown in robotium

Tags: android, robotium

what is the flow of the program in robotium.I mean are  setup() and teardown() called for every testcase separately ??

option 1
setup()
TC01
teardown()

setup()
TC02
teardown()

or option2

setup()
TC01
TC02
TC03
teardown()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Setup is called before every test method and teardown is called after every test method.
So the answer is option 1.